# The local property of a function has non-vanishing partial derivative of third order?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

The function $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ has continuous partial derivatives of at least order $4$. And 
$$f_x=f_y=f_{xx}=f_{yy}=f_{xy}=0$$
at $(0,0)$.

Also, at least one partial derivatives of order $3$ does not vanish at $(0,0)$.

Now how to show that  **$f$ can
have neither a local maximum nor a local minimum at this critical point.**

My attempt: I try to use the Taylor expansion, just like what we did when we introduced the Hessian matrix. However, the case of second order is totally different with the case of third order.

Answer (score 2):

By Taylor's theorem you have
$$f(x,y)=f(0,0)+p(x,y)+o\bigl(r^3\bigr)\qquad\bigl(r:=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\to0\bigr)\ ,\tag{1}$$
whereby $p$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $3$ (hence odd) that does not vanish identically. It follows that $p$ has a positive maximum $\mu>0$  and a negative minimum $-\mu<0$ on the unit circle $S^1$. Using $(1)$ you can then easily show that $f(x,y)-f(0,0)$ assumes in any neighborhood of $(0,0)$ strictly positive  as well as negative values.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why $p(x,y)$ can always have a positive maximum and negative minimum simultaneously?

Comment: I know how to prove the above statement now! Thank you!